# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.bindImportPath(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-8

When switching coldfusion versions, from 8 to 10. Once my Tomcat server is up and running, when i try to access any coldfusion page, I keep getting this error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.bindImportPath(Ljava/lang/String;)V`

But once i go to that file and make any change and save it, it starts working.

I've tried clearing template cache from the coldfusion administrator but no luck.

**UPDATE**:

Given this situation. What would be a possible solution to avoid having to do this tedious process?

Comment: Don't really see a question here....

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a bunch of residual precompiled files in your `WEB-INF/cfclasses` directory that were compiled with CF8...

Comment: @ScottStroz my question is what do i do so that i don't have to go edit and save every coldfusion file.

Comment: @Adam Cameron, so what do you suggest i do?

Comment: First things first, confirm the files are there, otherwise this discussion is a waste of everyone's time. Secondly, if they are there... get rid of them! NB: if someone asks you - in a comment - for clarification of your question, then *update the question*, don't just reply in the comment.

Comment: @AdamCameron They files are indeed there. I know because once i edit the file and save it. Then it works.

Comment: Right. So *delete them*. That's most likely your problem. It would not at all surprise me if at least some of the functionality in CF8 doesn't compile in a way compatible with CF10.

Comment: I'm not sure what files to delete. On my project or on coldfusion directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82547/discussion-between-victor-ramos-and-adam-cameron).

Comment: "... files in your WEB-INF/cfclasses directory ... get rid of them... delete them". I'm not sure what's unclear about that? But just to say the same thing again: delete all the files in the WEB-INF/cfclasses directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the CF Admin, you can clear the cache there.